# I need to test my IOS app off of localhost port 5000 running on my mac

Tags: ios, swift, typescript, backend

I am currently developing an app for IOS and need to test a few things on the physical phone. I have a beckend written in typescript running off of port:5000. The app connects to the backend via port:5000 using API calls. Whenever I try and running it by just plugging it in and running off of xcode, the UI works fine but when it comes to logging in or any functions that require the database, it does not work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You will need to find the ip address of your Mac and have your app connect to that.  Alternatively, use Ngrok.io and you can have a real dns address with https that maps to your local server

Comment: Localhost can only be used in iPhone app running in simulator